# Facing issues with sending mail via unix to mailbox with mailx

Tags: unix, ksh, mailx

I am trying to send a HTML report mail to my id from unix box with mailx command

mailx -s test -r user@tgtrg.com abc@gmail.com < /tmp/start.html

But I getting the output on mail as plain text with HTML tags instead of html report

I only need to use mailx command for this

Can you please advise

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$ mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "test" -r user@tgtrg.com abc@gmail.com < /tmp/start.html
```